# Extjs 4.1 Tooltip and DragNDrop

Tags: extjs, tooltip

I have the following problem. I create a bunch of images (preview images for widgets). And these images should be used to drag and drop these to the desired place where the widget should be and i want to show a tooltip on these also. This is the code i have:

```
var img = Ext.create('Ext.Img', {
            xtype: 'image',
            x: 1210,
            y: 110,
            height: 100,
            margin: 5,
            width: 100,
            js_clsName: z.js_classname,
            src: '/js/resources/images/widgetPreview/' + z.ident + '.png',
            listeners: {
                afterrender: {
                    fn: createDD,
                    scope: this
                }
            }
        });
        img.tip = Ext.create('Ext.tip.ToolTip', {
            target: img.el,
            trackMouse: true,
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            listeners: {
                beforeshow: function (tip) {
                    console.log(tip);
                    tip.update('asdasd');
                    return true;
                }
            }
        });
```

But the tooltip is never shown however the drag and drop works like a charm. Could you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Already got it, the problem is, that img.el was undefined, so i have to add the tip later.